# Java components proportional to window size (JavaFX)

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, layout

I need some help getting components scaled on my scene graph. In the following image I have the components on the top, well spaced and everything looks nice and normal.

[image]

I did that by setting the padding on the top menu with

**menu.setPadding(new Insets(30, 0, 30, 30));**

and **HBox.setMargin(button, new Insets(0,0,0,370));** for the button where 370 is the padding between the field and the button. Also, the text field has a preferred width of 400.

However, when I expand the window I realize the preferred width I set for the text field does not change and it is small, and the margins of the button also change, so I don't know how to set this numbers proportional to the size of the window. I am not sure if I fix this with CSS or simply java methods.

[image]

This is the code that deals with the top part where components have the issue when maximizing the window. 'pane' is an instance of BorderPane.

```
private void setTopMenu() {

 menu = new HBox();
 menu.setPadding(new Insets(30, 0, 30, 30));

 button = new Button("ABCD ABCD ABCD"); 

 tf = new TextField();
 tf.setPromptText("search"); 
 tf.setPrefWidth(400);
 tf.setId("text-field");

 top.getChildren().addAll(tf, button);

 HBox.setMargin(button, new Insets(0,0,0,370));

 pane.setTop(menu);
}
```

Comment: If you just need to resize the components inside the `TopMenu`, can't you `bind` the window's width to the width of your `Button` and `TextArea`'s width?

Comment: but how? @MarcoLuzzara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways:

- the first one is the easiest but also the less flexible:

  ```
  HBox.setHgrow(button, Priority.ALWAYS);
  HBox.setHgrow(tf, Priority.ALWAYS);
  ```

  Specifying the `Priority` you can decide how the additional space between the components and the `HBox` will be filled.
- Using the `Property` binding:

  ```
  button.prefWidthProperty().bind(menu.widthProperty().divide(3));
  ```

  In this example your `button` will be resized to 1/3 of the `menu`'s `WidthProperty` everytime this last property changes.
  [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) is better explained.

Comment: Also note that using a `GridPane` (with a single row), you can specify the widths of the columns as percentages; so you can get the same result as the second option without the binding.

Comment: Yes, he could have used `ColumnConstraint` and the `setPercentWidth` method. You were right to make us notice it.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoLuzzara for introducing me to bindings, I'm impressed and I did not know about it before. I got almost the result I wanted. Instead of binding to menu (like in your answer) I manage to bind to the scene width. However, the margins still change, is there any way I can bind the margins of the button to the scene width too? I did a quick search and I found bindings for padding, but that would not work out for me. Thanks again

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara As I said I ended up binding to the scene instead of the menu with **button.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(6))** I'm happy now with width of the button as I change the screen size with the mouse, which was the main purpose of this question. But as you can see, i set the margins of the button and passed a new Insets Object as an argument in the _setMargins()_ method, but those margins change as I maximize o make any changes to the screen. So can I bind the margins as I did with the button width, so those changes in the margin are something I specified?

Comment: @c2J You said that you found out about padding binding instead of margin binding, but it did not work for you. I guess you have used `paddingProperty`, can you show us your not-working code?